# Dualbooting Ubuntu and windows and can't boot into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04

Recently dualbooting Ubuntu and Windows and it was working fine but now when I go in to select which one I wanna boot into it goes black screen and then just boots into Ubuntu

Edit: it no longer automatically goes into Ubuntu but now Windows doesn't show up

SOLVED: Ran boot repair and now both Ubuntu and Windows show up :)

````
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair  ```
````

Comment: I meant to type 22.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use tools like [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to change the dualboot options. If one of the options is missing you can add a new entry and specify a path where the OS is installed.

If it still doesn't work you can [check this page](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and try more of their solutions.